# MKOverlay doesn't render properly close to 180th meridian (swift)

Tags: swift, mapkit

I want to display a pair of `MKOverlay` over a `MapKit` `mapView`. They render fine. This is how they look.

[Properly rendered MKOverlays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF6Gm.jpg)

Once I start to approach the 180th meridian, things get weird. For some reason, both `MKCircle` and `MKGeodesicPolyline` disappear. If I pan a little further, only `MKGeodesicPolyline` appears.

[Only MKGeodesicPolyline properly rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Elg.jpg)

I made sure that none of the latitudes exceed 180 and -180. Here's a snippet that does that:

```
//I know the math here could be a little bit better but this was just a temporary fix

if newCoordinates.longitude > 180 {
    newCoordinates.longitude = -(180 + (180 - newCoordinates.longitude))
}else if newCoordinates.longitude < -180 {
    newCoordinates.longitude = 180 + (180 + newCoordinates.longitude)
}

if newCoordinates.latitude > 90 {
    newCoordinates.latitude = 90
}else if newCoordinates.latitude < -90 {
    newCoordinates.latitude = -90
}
```

I did a little bit of searching and I've found out, that `MapKit` might not be able to display a polyline passing the 180th meridian, but that could be solvable by drawing two polylines (1. START to -180 & 2. 180 to END). But that would only solve a half of my problem. `MKCircle` also disappears for some reason, even though the coordinates are correct. What can I do about it? Hope you can help. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to increase the altitude that the circle is drawn at? I'm not super familiar with MapKit, but have you considered z-fighting to be the culprit? Or does MK not work that way?

Comment: As far as I know, that should not be a problem. It renders fine pretty much everywhere else on the world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve this issue was to draw my own lines in a view on top of a `MapView`, since I couldn't find a better way. It works fine, it just required a lot of work.